# How to use boolean variable in Jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline JOB with 3 stages

stage1 --> echo "stage1"

stage2 --> echo "stage2"

stage3 --> echo "stage3"

I want to execute stage1 and stage3 in all the scenarios. 
My requirement is to decide whether to execute the stage 2 or not using the boolean variable Flag_Var

Example: 
Execute stage1

If Flag_Var = 'Y'
   stage2 should execute
end if

Execute stage3

Code is mentioned below:

```
pipeline
{
agent any  
   stages
   {
      stage('Stage1')
                  {        
          steps
                                  {
            script
             { 
                node
                {

                }
                echo " Successfully executed Stage1"
                echo “$params.Flag_Value “
            }
          }
        }


          stage('Stage2')
                  {
                    when {
              expression { params.Flag_Value == "true"}
             }


          steps
                                  {
            script
             { 
                node
                {

                }
                echo " Successfully executed Stage2"
            }
          }
        }


                  stage('Stage3')
                  {        
          steps
                                  {
            script
             { 
                node
                {

                }
                echo " Successfully executed Stage3"
            }
          }
        }  
   }
}
```

Comment: Add some more info what you tried so far.

Comment: Added the code. The code always skip the stage2 even whether I select Boolean option or not.

Comment: 1. You should not name your param "Boolean", this may introduce a clash with a reserved word. 2. You should not compare your boolean parameter with a string of four letters, namely "t", "r", "u", and "e". 3. You should not attach screenshots when pasting your code as text would lead to better results.

Comment: Thanks MaratC! I deleted the snapshot and pasted the code. Also, modified Boolean into Flag_Value.   I am getting the value of Flag_Value as "true" in stage1. But dont know how to execute stage2 if the Flag_Value is true.

Comment: Can't see any `params` in your pipeline.

Comment: Flag_Value is Parameterized using Jenkins option(Enabled the option "This project is Parameterized" with Boolean parameter's name as Flag_Value).